# Регулярное выражение различающее из какого набора строка

Tags: алгоритм, регулярные-выражения

Есть два набора строк.
Белый список:

```
bhdgffhfa
aggjjaaga
hbefebhfi
dbceeabih
ihifdbhhf
djacfjbae
ibjbeigac
jaffigdad
aaaaaaaaj
dgifecchi
dcbhgjaaf
eedfbcedb
aaaaaaabf
beaajbihg
aaaaaaaag
eacccdjeh
aaaaaaaad
hehcijfhc
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaabc
jfdhdeice
```

И черный список:

```
aaaaaaaai
ehigcbgjd
hgjdeajec
aaaaaaabe
haebgiggc
aaaaaaaba
aaaaaaaaf
bfjhehbcf
diieabefh
jhjcaeead
ifbjdgibf
dddbgcgai
bbcafhcif
hfjciccbi
fdbgidjdj
aaaaaaabb
jhdibgbfj
cfjbaijad
bhgjfacgi
ehhieihhh
abijjabda
```

Нужно написать регулярное выражение, не длинее 60 символов, способное различать из какого набора взята строка.
Например, если на входе программе дано `aaaaaaaaa`, программа должна решить, что это строка из белого списка.

**UPDATE**: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/regular-expresso/challenges/match-maker

Comment: @Abyx По условиям задачи такое невозможно

Comment: А что за метка hackerrank.com?

Comment: Вам, возможно, покажется интересным это: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/xkcd1313.ipynb

Comment: @Abyx, видимо задача на сообразительность.

Comment: @Oceinic "по  условиям задачи такое невозможно" - это значит, что достаточно что бы регулярка однозначно определила, что строка в белом списке без возможности пропуска левых строк - я правильно понял ?

Comment: ссылка на Хакерранк в вопросе недоступна для незарегистрированных участников. В этом вопросе она бессмысленна.

Comment: @Mike, как я понял, регулярка должна матчить все строки из белого списка и не должна матчить все строчки из черного. Строки не из списков может как матчить так и нет.

Comment: @VladD спасибо. это то что я искал

Comment: @Oceinic: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @Oceinic т.е. ваш вопрос решен ? я думал надо разные решения предлагать, т.к. конкурс

Comment: Да, вопрос решен.

Comment: Пока не очевидно, что выражение укладівается в 60 символов

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Возможно получение двух решающих паттернов: по попаданию в белый список (whitelist) и в чёрный список (blacklist).

Паттерн белого списка: `/ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad|abc|abf|acf|bei|bhh|cij|aaaaaaaaa/`
Паттерн чёрного списка: `/bg|ai|bb|ie|jc|jd|bd|cg|jh|aba|abe|aaaaaaaaf/`

Паттерн чёрного списка короче и допускает сжатие до 37 символов:
`/ai|b[bdg]|cg|ie|j[cdh]|ab[ae]|a{8}f/`
Но использование двух паттернов позволяет провести диагностику.

Решающие паттерны набираются из уникальных для соответствующего списка токенов по оптимизированному "жадному" алгоритму.

К рассмотрению приняты двух- и трёхсимвольные токены, а также 9-символьные токены, начинающиеся с "aaaaaaa".

Программа на языке PHP:

```
$whitelist = "
    bhdgffhfa
    aggjjaaga
    hbefebhfi
    dbceeabih
    ihifdbhhf
    djacfjbae
    ibjbeigac
    jaffigdad
    aaaaaaaaj
    dgifecchi
    dcbhgjaaf
    eedfbcedb
    aaaaaaabf
    beaajbihg
    aaaaaaaag
    eacccdjeh
    aaaaaaaad
    hehcijfhc
    aaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaabc
    jfdhdeice
";

$blacklist = "
    aaaaaaaai
    ehigcbgjd
    hgjdeajec
    aaaaaaabe
    haebgiggc
    aaaaaaaba
    aaaaaaaaf
    bfjhehbcf
    diieabefh
    jhjcaeead
    ifbjdgibf
    dddbgcgai
    bbcafhcif
    hfjciccbi
    fdbgidjdj
    aaaaaaabb
    jhdibgbfj
    cfjbaijad
    bhgjfacgi
    ehhieihhh
    abijjabda
    ";

//Генератор решающих токенов
function tokens_gen($whitelist, $blacklist){
    $white_tokens = [];
    $black_tokens = [];
    for($i=-1; $i< 12; $i++){
        $c = ($i<0) ? "" : chr(ord("a")+$i);    // сначала двухсимвольные токены
        $c = ($i==10) ? "aaaaaaa" : $c;         // последними - токены c "aaaaaaa"
        for($ord2=ord("a"); $ord2 <= ord("j"); $ord2++){
            for($ord3=ord("a"); $ord3 <= ord("j"); $ord3++){
                $ccc = $c.chr($ord2).chr($ord3);
                $pm_white = preg_match("/$ccc/", $whitelist); 
                $pm_black = preg_match("/$ccc/", $blacklist);
                if(($pm_white==1) && ($pm_black==0)) array_push($white_tokens, $ccc);
                if(($pm_black==1) && ($pm_white==0)) array_push($black_tokens, $ccc);
            }
        }
    }
    return [$white_tokens, $black_tokens];
}

// "Жадный" рекурсивный отбор токенов
function greedy($tokens, $list, $pat=""){
    $tokens_new = [];
    $ppp_max = "";
    foreach($tokens as $ppp){
        $p = ($pat=="")? $ppp: "$pat|$ppp";
        $sum = 0;
        foreach($list as $str) $sum += preg_match("/$p/", $str);
        if($sum > $sum_max){
            $ppp_max = $ppp;
            $sum_max = $sum;
        }
        if($sum > 0) array_push($tokens_new, $ppp);
    }
    if($ppp_max == "") return $pat;
    $pat = ($pat=="")? $ppp_max: "$pat|$ppp_max";
    $left = 'display: block; float: left; ';
    printf("<span style='$left'>Токенов:</span><span style='$left width:30px;' align='right'>%d</span>", count($tokens));
    printf("<span style='$left'>&emsp;Строк,&emsp;всего:</span><span style='$left width: 24px;' align='right'>%d</span>&emsp;по токену: $sum_max&emsp;", count($list));
    print("Токен: $ppp_max &emsp; Паттерн: $pat<br>");
    $list = preg_grep("/$ppp_max/", $list, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
    $pat = greedy($tokens_new, $list, $pat);
    return $pat;
}

// Перевод контрольных строк в массивы
$white = explode(chr(10), trim($whitelist));
foreach($white as &$w) $w=trim($w);
$black = explode(chr(10), trim($blacklist));
foreach($black as &$b) $b=trim($b);
$white_black = array_merge($white, $black);

// Получение решающих токенов
list($white_tokens, $black_tokens) = tokens_gen($whitelist, $blacklist);

// Получение жадных паттернов
print("Жадные паттерны:<br><br>");
$white_pattern = greedy($white_tokens, $white);
$black_pattern = greedy($black_tokens, $black);
//$black_pattern = 'ai|b[bdg]|cg|ie|j[cdh]|ab[ae]|a{8}f';
print("<br><br>white_pattern = $white_pattern<br>black_pattern = $black_pattern<br>");  

$left = 'display: block; float: left; ';
print("<br>Проверка:<br>");
foreach($white_black as $str){
    $in_white = preg_match("/$white_pattern/",$str);
    $in_black = preg_match("/$black_pattern/",$str);
    print("<br><span style='$left width:80px'>$str:</span>$in_white $in_black");
}
```

Результаты:

```
Жадные паттерны:

Токенов:108 Строк, всего:21 по токену: 3 Токен: ce   Паттерн: ce
Токенов:108 Строк, всего:18 по токену: 2 Токен: ag   Паттерн: ce|ag
Токенов:88 Строк, всего:16 по токену: 2 Токен: fe   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe
Токенов:81 Строк, всего:14 по токену: 2 Токен: ff   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff
Токенов:67 Строк, всего:12 по токену: 2 Токен: aaj   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj
Токенов:49 Строк, всего:10 по токену: 1 Токен: cd   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd
Токенов:41 Строк, всего:9 по токену: 1 Токен: dc   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc
Токенов:33 Строк, всего:8 по токену: 1 Токен: aad   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad
Токенов:28 Строк, всего:7 по токену: 1 Токен: abc   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad|abc
Токенов:26 Строк, всего:6 по токену: 1 Токен: abf   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad|abc|abf
Токенов:24 Строк, всего:5 по токену: 1 Токен: acf   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad|abc|abf|acf
Токенов:22 Строк, всего:4 по токену: 1 Токен: bei   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad|abc|abf|acf|bei
Токенов:18 Строк, всего:3 по токену: 1 Токен: bhh   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad|abc|abf|acf|bei|bhh
Токенов:11 Строк, всего:2 по токену: 1 Токен: cij   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad|abc|abf|acf|bei|bhh|cij
Токенов:5 Строк, всего:1 по токену: 1 Токен: aaaaaaaaa   Паттерн: ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad|abc|abf|acf|bei|bhh|cij|aaaaaaaaa
Токенов:118 Строк, всего:21 по токену: 5 Токен: bg   Паттерн: bg
Токенов:118 Строк, всего:16 по токену: 2 Токен: ai   Паттерн: bg|ai
Токенов:82 Строк, всего:14 по токену: 2 Токен: bb   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb
Токенов:75 Строк, всего:12 по токену: 2 Токен: ie   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb|ie
Токенов:67 Строк, всего:10 по токену: 2 Токен: jc   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb|ie|jc
Токенов:53 Строк, всего:8 по токену: 2 Токен: jd   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb|ie|jc|jd
Токенов:37 Строк, всего:6 по токену: 1 Токен: bd   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb|ie|jc|jd|bd
Токенов:24 Строк, всего:5 по токену: 1 Токен: cg   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb|ie|jc|jd|bd|cg
Токенов:18 Строк, всего:4 по токену: 1 Токен: jh   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb|ie|jc|jd|bd|cg|jh
Токенов:12 Строк, всего:3 по токену: 1 Токен: aba   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb|ie|jc|jd|bd|cg|jh|aba
Токенов:5 Строк, всего:2 по токену: 1 Токен: abe   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb|ie|jc|jd|bd|cg|jh|aba|abe
Токенов:3 Строк, всего:1 по токену: 1 Токен: aaaaaaaaf   Паттерн: bg|ai|bb|ie|jc|jd|bd|cg|jh|aba|abe|aaaaaaaaf


white_pattern = ce|ag|fe|ff|aaj|cd|dc|aad|abc|abf|acf|bei|bhh|cij|aaaaaaaaa
black_pattern = bg|ai|bb|ie|jc|jd|bd|cg|jh|aba|abe|aaaaaaaaf

Проверка:

bhdgffhfa:1 0
aggjjaaga:1 0
hbefebhfi:1 0
dbceeabih:1 0
ihifdbhhf:1 0
djacfjbae:1 0
ibjbeigac:1 0
jaffigdad:1 0
aaaaaaaaj:1 0
dgifecchi:1 0
dcbhgjaaf:1 0
eedfbcedb:1 0
aaaaaaabf:1 0
beaajbihg:1 0
aaaaaaaag:1 0
eacccdjeh:1 0
aaaaaaaad:1 0
hehcijfhc:1 0
aaaaaaaaa:1 0
aaaaaaabc:1 0
jfdhdeice:1 0
aaaaaaaai:0 1
ehigcbgjd:0 1
hgjdeajec:0 1
aaaaaaabe:0 1
haebgiggc:0 1
aaaaaaaba:0 1
aaaaaaaaf:0 1
bfjhehbcf:0 1
diieabefh:0 1
jhjcaeead:0 1
ifbjdgibf:0 1
dddbgcgai:0 1
bbcafhcif:0 1
hfjciccbi:0 1
fdbgidjdj:0 1
aaaaaaabb:0 1
jhdibgbfj:0 1
cfjbaijad:0 1
bhgjfacgi:0 1
ehhieihhh:0 1
abijjabda:0 1
```

Проверка показала, что все паттерны работают.
Схема с полным "жадным" перебором дала такие же результаты.

Comment: Да, черный список оказался более сжимабельным)

Comment: @Mi Ke Bu Он явно меньше.

Answer (score 4):

#### Ответ:

```
/ag|c[de]|dc|fe|g[df]|aa[dj]|ab[cf]|b[aeh]{2}|bjb|cij|a{9}/
```

#### Проверка:

```js
var W=['bhdgffhfa','aggjjaaga','hbefebhfi','dbceeabih','ihifdbhhf','djacfjbae','ibjbeigac','jaffigdad','aaaaaaaaj','dgifecchi','dcbhgjaaf','eedfbcedb','aaaaaaabf','beaajbihg','aaaaaaaag','eacccdjeh','aaaaaaaad','hehcijfhc','aaaaaaaaa','aaaaaaabc','jfdhdeice'],
   B=['aaaaaaaai','ehigcbgjd','hgjdeajec','aaaaaaabe','haebgiggc','aaaaaaaba','aaaaaaaaf','bfjhehbcf','diieabefh','jhjcaeead','ifbjdgibf','dddbgcgai','bbcafhcif','hfjciccbi','fdbgidjdj','aaaaaaabb','jhdibgbfj','cfjbaijad','bhgjfacgi','ehhieihhh','abijjabda'];

var text="ag|c[de]|dc|fe|g[df]|aa[dj]|ab[cf]|b[aeh]{2}|bjb|cij|a{9}",
   reg=new RegExp(text);
document.write('<b>Длина выражения</b><br>С границами - '+reg.toString().length)
document.write('<br>Только символы - '+text.length)
document.write('<br><b>Тесты</b><br>Из белого '+W.filter(e=>reg.test(e)).length+'/'+W.length)
document.write('<br>Из черного '+B.filter(e=>reg.test(e)).length+'/'+B.length)
```

#### Решение по шагам

- Первым делом определим алфавит: в задаче используются символы `abcdefghij`
- Регулярное выражение будет определять принадлежность по уникальным для списка кускам (токен). Списка два - белый `W` и черный `B`, я выбрал белый список, просто он первый. **Попробуйте с черным, возможно там есть более короткое решение?)**.
- Токены сначала нужно найти. Сгенерируем 2, 3, 4-символьные множества:

  ```
  function set(lev,str){
      //set(2) - "aa,ab, ... ,jh,ji,jj", строкой пока компактнее
      lev--; str=str||"";
      return "abcdefghij".split('').map(function(e){
          return lev>0 ? set(lev,str+e) : str+e;
      }).join();
  }
  //"aa","ab",...,"jjji","jjjj" - массив
  sets=[].concat(set(2),set(3),set(4)).join().split(',')
  ```
- Для каждого токена определим, сколько раз он встречается в списках `W` и `B`.

  ```
  var freqs=sets.map(function(token){return {
     t:token,
     w:W.filter(function(e){return ~e.indexOf(token);}).length,
     b:B.filter(function(e){return ~e.indexOf(token);}).length
  };});
  ```
- Определим список токенов, уникальных для `W` и не содержащих в себе меньших токенов

  ```
  uniq=freqs.filter(function(e){//берем уникальные для W
     return e.w>0 && e.b==0;
  }).filter(function(big,i,arr){//выкидываем избыточные - содержащие других
     return undefined==arr.find(function(small){//содержу ли другой, меньше и лаконичнее?
        return big.t.length>small.t.length && ~big.t.indexOf(small.t);
     });
  });
  //выводим списком с частотами - что одним выстрелом многих зайцев бьет?
  uniq.map(x=>x.t+'\t'+x.w).join('\n')
  //выводим через | для тестов в regex101.com и им подобных сервисах
  uniq.map(x=>x.t).join('|')
  ```
- Минимизация количества токенов. Берем http://regex101.com, белый и черный списки, полученную регулярку `x|y|...|z` и по одному пробуем убирать токены из регулярного выражения, следя за тем, чтобы в белом списке в каждом элементе был найден хотя бы один токен. Для особых случаев вписываем токен руками (пример - `a{9}`)
- Оптимизация символов. Имеем регулярное выражение, покрывающее белый список, но:

  - Некоторые токены отличаются символами в одной позиции.

    - XX: `cd|сe` можно превратить в `c[de]`.

      *Польза = -1`|`-1`c`+2`[]` = 0 (полезна при похожести больше чем 2 токенов)*
    - XXX: `aad|aaj` превращаем в `aa[dj]`.

      *Польза = -1`|`-2`a`+2`[]` = -1 символ*
  - Некоторые токены отличаются символами в двух позициях.

    - XXX: `bae|bea|bhh` - `b[aeh]{2}`. Тут мы разширяем список токенов **и это опасно**. Но нам повезло и токены `baa|bee|bah|beh|bha|bhe` отсутствуют в черном списке, и эта расширяющая не сломает результат.

      *Польза = -2`|`-2`b`-3`eah`+2`[]`+3`{2}` = -2 символа*

P.S: Теоретически, поиск похожих, формирование замен и проверку списка-антогониста можно бы автоматизировать с помощью алгоритма Левинштейна (как в Word - похожие слова) и кластеризации, но мне было влом и количество токенов не такое уж большое для ручного, творческого процесса

Comment: А откуда взялся вариант `a{9}`?

Comment: Он как раз особый случай -> **вписан руками**. Мой код не ищет готовый ответ, в отличие от вашего кода, он просто помогает перелопатить тонны данных и откинуть заведомо бесполезные сочетания.

Comment: Если код решает задачу - значит, он отлажен.